# Templated objects within templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a sorted list of regions in an image using templates. The class defined here has its implementation further down in the same file.

```
template <typename RegionType>
class SortedType
{
    public:
        SortedType();
        ~SortedType();
        void makeEmpty();
        bool isFull() const;
        int lengthIs() const;
        void retrieveItem( RegionType&, bool& );
        void insertItem( RegionType  );
        void deleteItem( RegionType  );
        void resetList();
        bool isLastItem() const;
        void getNextItem( RegionType& );

    private:
        int length;
        NodeType<RegionType> *listData;
        NodeType<RegionType> *currentPos;
};
```

The node struct definition is:

```
template <typename DataType>
struct NodeType
{
   DataType info;
   NodeType<DataType> *next;
};
```

when I attempt to compile the code, I get the error: error: SortedType is not a type on the line where I prototype a function to use the SortedType class. I think it has something to do with the templates I am using for the SortedType class and the NodeType class is causing some sort of problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

*edit*
The prototyped function that the first error appears on is:

```
int computeComponents(ImageType &, ImageType &, SortedType &);
```

I have errors in all function prototypes that use the SortedType class. NodeType is declared before SortedType.

Comment: show the line where you prototype a function to use the SortedType class; or the lines the error(s) correspond to

Comment: looks fine provided NodeType declared before SortedType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int computeComponents(ImageType &, ImageType &, SortedType &);
```

should be

```
template <typename RegionType>
int computeComponents(ImageType &, ImageType &, SortedType< RegionType > &);
```

Comment: I had to add the template designation to the implementation of the functions as well, but once I did, it compiled! Thank you so much!